# Example of where the Mean Value Theorem of Integrals Fails

Tags: calculus, analysis

A circumstance where the Mean Value Theorem for Integrals fails is when the function is integrable but discontinuous.

The Mean Value Theorem for Integrals is,

$f(c)=\frac{1}{b-a}\int_{a}^{b}f(x)$

So if we want to prove it "fails" for a specific integral, then I assume we would want to prove that $f(c)$ takes on two different values. However, I really don't have any ideas for a discontinuous integral that would be simple to calculate yet suitable for the counterexample. A few suggestion would be really appreciated.

Comment: Unit Step functions are an interesting idea but I don't know how to find a suitable example. I think I just lack the creativity to think of one...

Comment: You've only stated constants. I need a specific integral for when the the MTV fails.

Answer (score 1):

> I assume we would want to prove that $f(c)$ takes on two different values.

No, that's not how it fails. $f$ is a function, and therefore, by definition, no matter what $c$ is (as long as it's in the domain), $f(c)$ can only have a single value.

However, there is something else that can fail. Note what the mean value theorem says:

> [...] **there exists** a $c\in [a, b]$ such that [...]

If $f$ is discontinuous, then it's possible that any candidate $c$ either makes $f(c)$ too large or too small. In that case there is no $c$ that makes $f(c)$ have the exact right value.

The easiest way to make sure that there is no such $c$ is to make $f$ take only two values, and make sure $\frac{1}{b-a}\int_a^bf(x)\,dx$ is not one of those two values.

Comment: Care to provide an example of such an $f$? I don't think I have the creativity or experience with discontinuous functions to think of a good example on my own.

Comment: @Dylan I have told you exactly how to create your own example, including some notes on how one would typically think to even conceive of an example. Will has given you an entirely concrete example. What more do you want?